# Chrome, Firefox can't play video but IE can

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, plugins

I tried following code,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <object id="mediaplayer" 
     classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
     codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701"  
     standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." 
     type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="310">
         <param name="filename" value="videos\videofile_96.mp4">
         <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
         <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
         <param name="autostart" value="true">
         <param name="showcontrols" value="false">
         <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
         <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
         <embed src="videos\videofile_96.mp4" autostart="true" 
                showcontrols="false" showstatusbar="0" 
                bgcolor="white" width="320" height="310">
     </object>
</body>
```

So when I tried to play this video in `FireFox` and `Chrome`, wasn't played, but `IE` managed to play it.

Later I tried to add Windows `Media Player plugin`,`Activex Control Plugin` to both, but still problem remains the same.

Can anybody help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with (both times you use) `videos\videofile_96.mp4` -- those should be forward slashes (`/`). IE plays nice with `\`, but other browsers won't, necessarily.

Also, the `\` indicates to me that you may be using this on a local machine, rather than through a web server; this will definitely cause problems in non-IE browsers.

Comment: So you mean to say it will play online videos. I just need it to replace with `URL` ??

Comment: Yes, if you use a proper URL there, that will fix the problem, unless you have other issues.

Comment: I'm not sure about the live video part; you should try it and see. Please remember to accept an answer if it helped solve your problem! :)

Comment: K I vl try.. But do you know any other way to play live video??

Comment: Not off the top of my head. You should try it, and then post another question if you run into troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use ActiveX which is IE specific. Try html5 video instead and it will work in Firefox and chrome